# Google Cloud socket.io server, client not keeping persistent connection

Tags: android, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, socket.io

I have a Node.js server using socket.io to connect Android apps and I've been hosting it locally by just running it in my IDE and connecting to my local IPv4 address but I want it to work without me having to keep my PC running constantly so I've tried using Google Cloud and managed to get it mostly working but the client doesn't keep the connection and disconnects consistently.

I followed [this tutorial](https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/cloud-nodejs/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1) up to step 4 after that I ran gcloud app deploy.

My Node.js server is in one file, it has these declarations at the top.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
```

I then have this for the initial client connection.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected.");
```

Everything inside of this is just listeners for what gets emitted by the client so I don't think they're the problem.

And then outside of that I have

```
server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening");
});
```

I don't know if anything from the package.json file is relevant but I can provide it if need be.

After deploying to Google Cloud using the [tutorial](https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/cloud-nodejs/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1) there are a few things in the logs that may be the reason behind the problem.

> Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/invalid" Address:127.0.0.1:8080

> Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"app/invalid" Address:127.0.0.1:8081

> Wait successful. Subject:"app/invalid" Address:127.0.0.1:8080 Attempts:97 Elapsed:485.916418ms

> App is listening on port 8080. We recommend your app listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable to take advantage of an NGINX layer on port 8080.

These might have simple solutions but I have very little experience with server hosting.

Once my Android client connects to the server, the log outputs "User connected." as it should, then around 10 seconds later it does it again and this repeats. There's no error I can see between the connections just a few socket.io POST/GET requests.

I tried adding session affinity to the app.yaml but hasn't solved it either.

This is my app.yaml if any changes need to be made here

```
runtime: nodejs16
env: standard
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Thanks for any help, if I need to provide any other files I can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket communication requires persistent network connections. So, **App Engine Flexible** provides an option to keep the network connection alive.
I think you are deploying your app in **App Engine Standard** , which does not support this option.
So, you can deploy your app in **App Engine Flexible** and you need to include the following configuration in your app.yaml

```
network:
    session_affinity: true
```

For refence on session affinity, please refer to this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity#session_affinity
So, your updated app.yaml can look like this

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

Please refer to this page for supported yaml configuration for flexible environment - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml

Comment: That did seem to have fixed it at first, but after testing it a bit more it's still not fully working.

I'm now getting the "User connected" output, multiple times in a row even when only connecting 1 client. 

I'm not on good Internet right now, so that may be the problem, but if not would changing the split health checks in the app.yaml documentation you linked be something to look at?

Comment: I just had a look at the versions tab in the app engine and it says that there are 2 instances of it. I did notice after I first deployed it, that the "Server is listening" log was outputted twice which is in the server.listen, so could also be something to do with that

Comment: If it is simple application, i suggest to keep your min and max instances to 1 only. Why because, if max instances is not set to 1, based on the load app scales automatically by adding more instances. In that scenario, if socket clients information is not stored in a common database, then a particular instance can only know about the sockets that are connected to it.

Comment: So, if you want your app to scale, which means based on the load if you want number of instances to be increased then there should be a mechanism which stores all socket clients information across all the instances. So that, at any given point of time you will know all the socket clients that are connected @Jamie

Comment: Setting the instances to 1 seems to have done the job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Messages you have pasted are most likely not indicating a problem. Your application is running in a sandbox environment for which a container instance and a web server must be initialized the first time that your app engine service receives a request. This is also called [Loading request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#loading_requests) and the messages you see indicate the startup of your container instance and your webserver.
You can take a look at Google's own [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled) regarding handling requests in node.js or follow a [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart).
If there are no other logs during the disconnection, I would suggest checking  the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) to see if you're not exceeding any.